# Middleman i18n: language files (YML) don't seem to be recognised

Tags: internationalization, middleman

I have a working Middleman v4 website. Now I'd like to add a second language:

```
activate :i18n, :langs => [:de, :en]
```

I have created the following files:

/source/locales/de.yml:

```
---
de:
  hello: "Hallo"
```

/source/locales/en.yml:

```
---
en:
  hello: "Hello"
```

But when using `= t(:hello)` somewhere in a template, I just get `translation missing: de.hello`.

I already restarted the server, but no success. I have tried to break the validity of a YML file (just replaced the content with `de:::`), hoping that Middleman would produce a parsing error or anything like that, but nothing happened (the Terminal continued to display `== LiveReloading path: /locales/de.yml`).

I wonder whether Middleman doesn't find/parse my `locales` YML files at all?

Answer (score 0):

The locals folder needs to be under the root directory and not sources. Reference the structure here: https://middlemanapp.com/basics/directory-structure/